# MVC DropDownListFor SelectedValue with collection issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

First of All Sorry to post the same question thought there are lot of posts already available. I tried all possible ways and finally I dint have any other option other than posting the same question.

I wanted to bind a enum to a DROPDOWNLISTFOR, but the text in a friendly manner. so In the controller I am binding the selectlist like

```
List<SelectListItem> formTypeSelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (FormType type in ItemHelper.EnumToList<FormType>())
        {
            SelectListItem formTypeList = new SelectListItem();
            formTypeList.Text = ItemHelper.GetEnumDescription(type);
            formTypeList.Value = Convert.ToString((int)type);
                            formTypeList.Value = Convert.ToString((int)type);

            formTypeSelectList.Add(formTypeList);
        }

        item.FormTypeSelectListItem = formTypeSelectList;`
```

My Entity has

```
public FormType FormType { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> FormTypeSelectListItem { get;  set; }

    public SelectList FinalSelectList
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(FormTypeSelectListItem, "Value", "Text", (int)FormType);
        }
    }
```

My view has

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Item.FormType, Model.Item.FinalSelectList, new { id = "ddlFormType" })%>
```

I even tried few other option for binding  views like

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Item.FormType,  new SelectListItem(Model.Item.FinalSelectList,"Value","Text",(int)Model.Item.formType)) %>
```

Nothing works, When I changed to HTML.DropdownList with a name specified it worked perfectly, but i wanted to bind with dropdownlistfor only.

I even tried adding different id, different name in view like

```
new{id="ddlformType",name="ddlformtype")
```

nothing worked. Can some one help me to fix this?

Thanks,
Akila

Answer (score 0):

DropDownListFor is looking for an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` for it's items.  Try just passing your `FormTypeSelectListItem` to the DropDownListFor method in place of your `FinalSelectList`.  You may have to cast the model property as an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Comment: I tried that option too but it dint work, even now I tried but it dint work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.now my code looks like<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Item.FormType, Model.Item.FormTypeSelectListItem)%> and I have changed the property to have iEnumerable

Comment: I was able to Fix this using [public class BoundEnum<T>
 {
  List<T> listOfValues;
  public Dictionary<T, string> ValueDictionary { get; private set; }


  public BoundEnum()
  {
   Initialize();
  }

  private void Initialize()
  {
   this.ValueDictionary = new Dictionary<T, string>();
   foreach (T value in (T[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
   {
    ValueDictionary.Add(value, Helpers.ItemHelper.GetEnumDescription(value as Enum));
   }
  }
 }]

Comment: Sorry I am new And I posted the code above, Now I have used in the view`<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Item.FormType, new SelectList(
        new BoundEnum<FormCenterENT.Enums.FormType>().ValueDictionary,
        "Key",
        "Value",
        Model.Item.FormType))%>`